# How to change background overlay of ContentDialog uwp

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am developing UWP Win10 App using VS2015. I am using ContenDialog to show a Modal Window / Popup. I need to change the Background Overlay color of ContentDialog. How to do this. There is no option/property even in the inner Style too.

I need to change the Overlay White Dim color to some other color like Blackish overlay/dim color etc...

See the pic.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need custom use control to have more control over the background. The default `ContenDialog` provide very bare bone setup and has limitations to the number of buttons / contents.

Comment: OK. but how to apply the custom dialog.

Comment: there is no quick way to modify the ContentDialog to meet your requirement. Create a grid as a background layer is one work around. But building a custom user control will be better and more flexible to changes.

Comment: Ok thank you dear! for your interest and valuable suggestion.
Yes ... the ContentDialog is difficult to modify and even there is no Overlay changing option ... So I applied the Grid and stretch it over the whole screen and made its background Gray with opacity 0.5 and then display a Custom user control over it. So it worked. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

The key resource to set is `SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush`

I use the following theme definition to target all ContentDialogs in my apps:

```
<!--  override the Dialog Background  -->
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentDialogDimmingThemeBrush" Color="#99FFFFFF" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" Color="#99000000" />
        <StaticResource x:Key="ContentDialogLightDismissOverlayBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentDialogDimmingThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorHighlightColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" Color="#99000000" />
        <StaticResource x:Key="ContentDialogLightDismissOverlayBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```