# UWP modal UserControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, modal-dialog, win-universal-app

I tried to create a modal UserControl because the ContentDialog control is difficult to modify.

[How to change background overlay of ContentDialog uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451389/how-to-change-background-overlay-of-contentdialog-uwp)

The title zone will be on the content zone(like a ContentDialog) but the background should be the same as the owerlay content.

[What i try to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K02J3.gif)

How should i do to create this modal UserControl?

EDIT:
Thanks for your answer!
Actualy i have my control

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestModal.ModalView">

<Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.5">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="test"/>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

A main page :
Xaml

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Click="Show_Click" />
</Grid>
</Page>
```

C#:

```
private void Show_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ModalView myModalView = new ModalView();
    Content = myModalView;
}
```

But how can i activate the user control? change content is not what i want to do.

Comment: If you want use user control in your page, you can use `<local:ModalView ></local:ModalView>` in XAML.

Comment: Thanks, now i use in my page <local:ModalView ></local:ModalView>, her visibility is "Collaped" and whith a Click event i set the visibility to "Visibility.Visible"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a control with an Grid for instance overlaying the complete UI. Give that grid for instance a black color with opacity 0.6 so you can see the underlying UI. Then just fill the Grid with controls you want to show. On events like 'click outside of the data area' (silent dismiss) or clicking a button ('close' or 'save' for instance) you can hide the UI again. And this can be packaged in a UserControl that can be used on other Pages.

---

If this is an answer to your question, please mark this as answer.

Comment: I edit my question with your answer, thanks for your help, it's my first post on stackoverflow and my first develpment with c# =) but how to activate this control?