# ContentDialog and app color

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

When modal content dialog is shown in Win10 Universal app the system draws a white mask over the background app to show it is disabled and the content dialog is modal.

This looks very bad for my app. How can I change this disabled app state color mask?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change background overlay of ContentDialog uwp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451389/how-to-change-background-overlay-of-contentdialog-uwp)

Comment: You can also see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159658/configuring-overlay-background-colour-for-contentdialog